# drag multiple nodes in d3 force directed layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js

**Precondition**: d3 force directed layout;
some nodes are selected by sequential clicking one by one (visually they become bigger and in the code pushed to array)

Is there a way to **drag** them all by picking one with the mouse the same way as files in the Windows explorer?

P.S. I'm getting very much answers here on stackoverflow without asking for a long time. This is my first question. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: @Dmitra Kyianytsia (aka John Veinmann), **What have you tried?** (-1 for not posting any attempts)

Comment: better late than never. Had the same problem and found an answer on @vasturiano 's github: https://github.com/vasturiano/3d-force-graph/blob/master/example/multi-selection/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way that I impemented the dragging of multiple nodes (based off of children) was by recording the displacement of the dragged node inside of my tick function with a variable whose scope allows the value to still exist the next time tick runs.

You will need an object where the key is a unique indentifier of the node being dragged and the value is a d3 selection of the nodes that you would like to translate/drag when the key node is dragged.

`dragObject` is the above-mentioned object.

`nodeData` is the d3 data of the principle node that you are dragging - ( d3.select(node uid).datum() ).

`offset.x` and `offset.y` make up the above-mentioned variable that was defined the last time tick was run.

```
var translateAllChildren = function (nodeData) {
    if (dragObject[nodeData.uid]) {
        dragObject[nodeData.uid]
            .attr("transform", function(d) {

                d.x = (d.x + offset.x);;
                d.y = (d.y + offset.y);

                return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this was old answer, but can you provide more details? :)

Comment: @Wexoni About anything specific?